# Composer set symlink path

Tags: composer-php, typo3, symlink

I set up TYPO3 via composer. Some of my packages are extensions and will be added to the extension folder.

```json
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "PACKAGES/*"
    }
],
"require": {
    "VENDOR/NAME": "^1.0",
}
```

That is okay. But I would like to create a folder in the packages folder which will be linked to `public/fileadmin/FOLDER`

Is that possible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to put my application in the package folder but create a symlink to it in another directory after composer install/update is called

Comment: Please be more specific. The reason to link a package with PHP code to public fileadmin could open a security issue.

Comment: What @ThomasLöffler wrote, if you need these things it should normally done hand-in-hand with the system administrator to adopt the configuration of the deployment process.